# Remote desktop XRDP not working for Pi 3 Model B+

Tags: pi-3b+

I would guess a similar question has been asked already, so any hint pointing me to this direction is welcome.

It would be my third Pi install and out of the blue I can't connect via XRDP as on the previous 2 installs.

I can Putty into the pi, and ping websites from the pi ...

however, trying to install xrdp on the pi I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install xrdp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf xrdp armhf 0.9.9-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/xrdp/xrdp_0.9.9-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
-bash: Do: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf xrdp armhf 0.9.9-1
-bash: Err:1: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $   404  Not Found [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
-bash: 404: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/xrdp/xrdp_0.9.9-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
-bash: E:: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
-bash: E:: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
-bash: Do: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf xrdp armhf 0.9.9-1
-bash: Err:1: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $   404  Not Found [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
-bash: 404: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/xrdp/xrdp_0.9.9-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
-bash: E:: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
-bash: E:: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pi@raspberrypi:~ $ Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
-bash: pi@raspberrypi:~: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ -bash: Do: command not found
-bash: -bash:: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pi@raspberrypi:~ $ Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf xrdp armhf 0.9.9-1
-bash: pi@raspberrypi:~: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ -bash: Err:1: command not found
-bash: -bash:: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pi@raspberrypi:~ $   404  Not Found [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
-bash: pi@raspberrypi:~: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ -bash: 404: command not found
-bash: -bash:: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pi@raspberrypi:~ $ E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/xrdp/xrdp_0.9.9-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
-bash: pi@raspberrypi:~: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ -bash: E:: command not found
-bash: -bash:: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pi@raspberrypi:~ $ E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
-bash: pi@raspberrypi:~: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ -bash: E:: command not found
-bash: -bash:: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ -bash: E:: command not found
```

I ran both update / upgrade and removed the VNC prior to attempting an XRDP install.
I can see the Pi on LAN and Putty into it.

However, all my attempts to XRDP into it's GUI via XRDP (as is nicely working for the first 2 installs) remain unfruitful ...

Any hint, directions ??
Pls. Contact: Breite_Gu[at]web.de

best regards
many thanks in advance
Gunter

Comment: You have a networking problem. Problem connecting to internet or a problem using IPv6. Can you add the output of `sudo apt update` to your query.

Comment: There is also something odd going on your system: bash uses output from apt-get as input on the command line.